# Parsing text file & counting pattern occurrences w/multiple loops using Scanner class

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am using multiple while loops with a scanner, I have both while loops working to the point that which ever one is before the other it will calculate correct results, however the while loops below will be broken.

I have tried adding break; into both but this is no help. What am I doing wrong ?

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(Coursework.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt")).useDelimiter(("[^A-Za-z']+"));

    int count = 0;
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    int numberOfConsonants = 0;
    int numberOfPunctuation = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    int numberOfChars = 0;

    String x = "";
    String nextLine = "";

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            nextLine = sc.nextLine();
            numberOfLines++;
            x = nextLine.toLowerCase().trim();
            for (int i = 0, n = x.length(); i < n; i++) {
                char c = x.charAt(i);
                numberOfChars++;
                if ((c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' ||
                     c == 'f' || c == 'g' || c == 'h' ||               
                     c == 'j' || c == 'k' || c == 'l' || 
                     c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'p' || 
                     c == 'q' || c == 'r' || c == 's' || 
                     c == 't' || c == 'v' || c == 'w' ||
                     c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')) {
                        numberOfConsonants++;

                }
                if ((c =='?'| c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '"')){
                    numberOfPunctuation++;
                }
            }
       }

       while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.next();
            count++; 
       }
}
```

Comment: `hasNextLine()` will return `true` until you consume all the lines of the file which means that when you get to the second loop, `sc.hasNext()` will return `false`

Comment: so is it impossible to use both on the same scanner?

Comment: Is not impossible, you just need to add another condition to the first loop so it will stop when you've done with that logic, for example `while(sc.hasNextLine() && numberOfLines < 1)` this will exit from the first loop after you read one line from the file.

Comment: so you would need to know the exact number of lines, could you count it and then apply the exit? so if i didn't know the number of lines but still wanted to exit the loop, could i still do that?

Comment: The loop will exit when you've read all the lines in the file, the problem is that since the first loop will read the entire file the second loop will not execute because there is nothing to read and `hasNext()` return `false`.

Comment: If you want to process the same file from the start using the logic in the second loop you will have to reopen the file.

Comment: Just re declare  the scanner before while loop.  You can't use same scanner.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, titus if you would like to just make a quick answer i will mark as correct

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your assignment required or which part of the Java language it was focused on having you learn, but if I wanted to parse and tally an input file similarly, I would probably do something like the following:

Where file.txt contains:

```
1. Aaaaa eiou foo!
2. bbbbb?
```

And the program was compiled and run as follows:

```
javac TextAnalyzer.java
java TextAnalyzer file.txt
```

The output is:

```
Text Analysis of file: file.txt

 characters:  27
 words:       6
 uppercase:   1
 lowercase:   16
 consonants:  7
 vowels:      11
 digits:      2
 punctuation: 4
 whitespace:  4
```

Here is the source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TextAnalyzer {

    public static int count(String line, Pattern pattern) {
        int count = 0;
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Pattern vowels      = Pattern.compile("[aeiouAEIOU]");
        Pattern consonants  = Pattern.compile("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstuvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]");
        Pattern punctuation = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");
        Pattern whitespace  = Pattern.compile("\\p{Space}");
        Pattern digits      = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}");
        Pattern uppercase   = Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}");
        Pattern lowercase   = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lower}");
        Pattern words       = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        Pattern characters  = Pattern.compile(".");

        int vowelCount       = 0;
        int consonantCount   = 0;
        int punctuationCount = 0;
        int whitespaceCount  = 0;
        int digitCount       = 0;
        int uppercaseCount   = 0;
        int lowercaseCount   = 0;
        int wordCount        = 0;
        int charCount        = 0;
        int lineCount        = 0;

        if (args[0].length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No filename provided");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                ++lineCount;
                vowelCount       += count(line, vowels);
                consonantCount   += count(line, consonants);
                punctuationCount += count(line, punctuation);
                whitespaceCount  += count(line, whitespace);
                digitCount       += count(line, digits);
                uppercaseCount   += count(line, uppercase);
                lowercaseCount   += count(line, lowercase);
                wordCount        += count(line, words);
                charCount        += count(line, characters);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't parse " + args[0] + "\n" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Text Analysis of file: " + args[0]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" characters:  "  + charCount);
        System.out.println(" words:       "  + wordCount);
        System.out.println(" uppercase:   "  + uppercaseCount);
        System.out.println(" lowercase:   "  + lowercaseCount);
        System.out.println(" consonants:  "  + consonantCount);
        System.out.println(" vowels:      "  + vowelCount);
        System.out.println(" digits:      "  + digitCount);
        System.out.println(" punctuation: "  + punctuationCount);
        System.out.println(" whitespace:  "  + whitespaceCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to add one to the word count or modify the pattern slightly.

Comment: that is an interesting way of doing it, i literally have to do all of that however i have done it another way  which i can fully explain haha but it is good to see how other people have done it!